# how to use .bak files

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

i want insert .bak in my asp.net project, how to use .bak file?
I use ms sql 2008 express.

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Open up SQL Management Studio Express, right-click on the Databases node and Restore Database... from the .bak file.